# Hide menu titles in Omega subtheme

Tags: theming

Can anyone help me how to delete or hide the menu titles (eg MAIN MENU title)?

I know how it is done when I do it on a static template but I cannot find it in Omega.

Answer (score 4):

If you display menu in block.
Select Configure block from the drop down that appears
On the next screen enter `<none>` in the Block title and then click Save block at the bottom of the page.
Or you can simply `display: none` via css.

Comment: There are accessibility impacts with removing the menu titles (read through the mountain of WCAG documents for the gory details).  `display: none` also has accessibility impacts, too.  See h5bp.com/v and the .visuallyhidden class in HTML5 Boilerplace for more details.